# Expansion of list comprehension leading to infinite loop in listing power sets

Tags: python, algorithm, list-comprehension, powerset

I have been trying to solve the problem of listing power sets on [Question 78](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/description/) on Leetcode. I ran into a [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/discuss/27356/5-lines-of-python) that uses list comprehensions and it works. I tried expanding it and following through with the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to make sure I get the correct syntax but I seem to be getting into an infinite loop.

> Given a set of distinct integers, nums, return all possible subsets
>   (the power set).
>
> Note: The solution set must not contain duplicate subsets.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Input: nums = [1,2,3]
> Output:
> [
>   [3],
>   [1],
>   [2],
>   [1,2,3],
>   [1,3],
>   [2,3],
>   [1,2],
>   []
> ]
> ```

The code in the solution is:

```
    def subsets(nums):
        nums.sort()
        result = [[]]
        for num in nums:
            result += [i + [num] for i in result]
        return result
```

The code with my change is:

```
  def subsets(nums):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :rtype: List[List[int]]
    """
    result = [[]]

    for num in nums:
      for list_ in result:
        result.append([num] + list_)
    return result
```

I think that in each iteration of the `for list_ in result:` loop, the result is getting bigger and so I wouldn't get to the end of it but why is it not the same case with the list comprehension? What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, you should never append to a list you're iterating. You could, however, create a shallow copy of it (`results_iter = list(results)`) and iterate through it, while you append to the original `result` list.

Comment: @Roberto, thanks for pointing an easy way of creating a shallow copy of a list. I didn't know using `list()` could be used on a list to creating a list. Other suggestions have involved importing modules.

Comment: Please don't do this: `class Solution(object):` If this is some requirement of some grading system, then strip your question down to a [mcve].

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, I removed what you requested to strip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because first `[i + [num] for i in result]` is resolved, and then once that is computed, the `result +=` part happens, which is different from yours where you append 1 by 1. The other solution appends all at once so there is no issue